# (Workaround Used) Excel VBA: Replacing a dictionary item in one class with a dictionary from a second class crashes Excel

Tags: excel, vba, class, dictionary

The issue I am having is with replacing an existing dictionary item with another dictionary pulled from a separate class.

Here is the main line of code. Whenever I try to use this code, Excel crashes.

```
Call fileList.Items(i).updbrList(branchInfo)
```

`fileList` is a dictionary, which stores an instance of a class, `fileInfo`.

From multiple step-throughs of the code, I think it is because I'm not able to pass the `connList` dictionary correctly, because `branch.connList` remains empty in the `updbrList` sub, even after completing `Property Get`.

The method `updbrList` is presented below. It collects a string `branchID` and a dictionary `connList` from the instance of another class, `branch`. I am trying to replace the current dictionary item `branch.brConn` with `branch.connList`.

```
'Class Module: File_Info
Private pbranchList As Scripting.Dictionary`

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pbranchList = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Sub addBranch(branch As Branch_Info)
    pbranchList.Add branch.branchID, branch.brConn
End Sub

Public Sub updbrList(branch As Branch_Info)
    pbranchList.Item(branch.branchID) = branch.connList
End Sub
```

The properties for `connList` are presented below:

```
'Class Module: Branch_Info
Private pconnList As Scripting.Dictionary

'Declare variantcopy subroutine
Private Declare Sub VariantCopy Lib "OleAut32" (pvarDest As Any, pvargSrc As Any)

Private Function GetByRefVariant(ByRef var As Variant) As Variant
    VariantCopy GetByRefVariant, var
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pconnList = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Let connList(pconnListi As Variant)
    Set pconnList = pconnListi
End Property
Public Property Get connList() As Variant
    connList = GetByRefVariant(pconnList)
End Property
```

Any help with this problem is much appreciated.
Please ask for additional info, if required.

Kind Regards,

Eeshwar

Comment: Since you know the type is a dictionary object, why pass it as Variant?

Comment: Mostly because I'm new to referencing in class modules. I used Variant for passing arrays before.

Comment: I got around this problem by removing the item and key from the dictionary and then adding a new item with the same key as before.